# report error: ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-23

We upgraded Apex to 23.1.5 and an app that was working fine in the previous version is throwing this error

> report error:
> ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table

It's a report and should be displaying data.  I can provide the code behind the screen if needed.

I was expecting the app to work the same as it did in the previous version, as we have not updated anything within the app code or setting wise.

```
SELECT s."ROWID",
  s."EMPLOYEE_NUMBER",
  NVL(p.full_name, 'Invalid') FULLNAME,
  s."DOCUMENT_TYPE",
  s."COST_CENTRE_PARENT",
  s."SIGNING_LIMIT",
  l.name ledger,
  a.organization_id
FROM "#OWNER#".xxapex142_signing_limits s
  , apps.per_all_people_f p
  , apps.per_all_assignments_f a
  , apps.gl_ledgers l
WHERE s.employee_number = p.employee_number (+)
 AND  p.person_id = a.person_id (+)
 AND  a.set_of_books_id = l.ledger_id (+)
 AND  l.short_name = 'DJR_PRIMARY'
 AND (
   UPPER(s.employee_number) LIKE '%'||NVL(UPPER(:P2_SEARCH_TEXT),'')||'%'
OR UPPER(p.full_name) LIKE '%'||NVL(UPPER(:P2_SEARCH_TEXT),'')||'%'
OR UPPER(s.cost_centre_parent) LIKE '%'||NVL(UPPER(:P2_SEARCH_TEXT),'')||'%'
OR UPPER(s.signing_limit) LIKE '%'||NVL(UPPER(:P2_SEARCH_TEXT),'')||'%'
OR UPPER(a.organization_id) LIKE '%'||NVL(UPPER(:P2_SEARCH_TEXT),'')||'%'
OR UPPER(l.name) LIKE '%'||NVL(UPPER(:P2_SEARCH_TEXT),'')||'%'
)
```

Comment: Who knows? You've probably checked what Oracle says about this error. If/as it didn't help, perhaps you should really post that piece of code.

Comment: Turn on debug at trace level which will capture the exact query that was run by APEX when the error occurs.  Its possible that the new version of APEX generates a slightly different query

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; the query that is generating the error; and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: Provide the view definition and the query against it.